# testing if a link directs to a correct page in django

Tags: django, testing

i am working with the django framework and i'm having trouble with testing the project.

i want to test whether a link redirects to the proper page or not.

i have a link in a page that redirect to another web page -

how can i test if - when the user is clicking the link he gets redirected to
the correct page?

for example: lets say i have:
 [redirect me](/second_link.html)

i want to know that when the user is clicking on "redirect me" he gets sent
to "second_link.html"

Comment: Look into using Google analytics for tracking. You can track every links clicked, etc.. If you are not looking for tracking, you might want to write unit tests to ensure the redirection is to the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use Selenium. First you have to install selenium for python from pip:

```
pip install selenium
```

Then if you want you can create most of the test from the selenium ide:

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

This is a firefox addon that allows you to record what you do browsing the web and transforming it into a selenium test for the language of your choice. You can record login into your website and clicking on the link, and then go to File -> export unittest as -> Python 2 unittest webdriver.

This would be a base test that you can save into your django app tests folder. It would have a couple of things left to do, like:

- Removing some unneeded code it might have generated that could make the test less readable.
- Inheriting the test class from LiveServerTestCase ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/ ) so the test runs the django webserver.
- Of course adding the assert that asks if your browser is on the correct website at the end of the test.